# How do Trinitarians reconcile Jesus is a spirit?

Tags: nature-of-god, trinity, christology, spirit

From my understanding of the Trinity (please correct me if I am wrong), the Trinity is God the Father, Jesus Christ, and the Holy Ghost as three separate beings (or personalities) but one God. They also are a spirit so they can be everywhere and are not confined to one place. Working with my understanding, I will proceed with my question.

In the New Testament we have a record of the physical birth of Christ, His ministry, and His death. We also read concerning His resurrection, or the rejoining of His spirit and body.

If Jesus Christ is a spirit in the Trinity, how do the Trinitarians reconcile this if the New Testament records His appearance with a physical body after the Resurrection?

-- Please correct my understanding of the Trinity if it is incorrect.

Comment: I believe different trinitarian doctrines will answer this questions differently.  Even if you tightened the scope, I'm not sure that there will be an answer which isn't opinion based.  Potentially the Catholics have documented their version.

Comment: "the Trinity is ... three separate beings (or personalities) but one God" This isn't how it's normally understood. Instead I think it's normally understood as three persons (not personalities) who are one being.

Comment: I'm not really sure what you think need reconciling...

Comment: IMHO the OP is trying to poke holes in the trinity.  There are much more glaring holes, such as "To whom did Jesus pray?" or "Why did Jesus say that he was going to the father?" or "Why did Jesus say that the father was greater than him?"  I agree with @curiousdannii, if you can reconcile these things, a little matter such as him being in a physical body after the resurrection appears small to me.

Comment: @curiousdannii - I figured there was some misunderstanding in the concept of the trinity, thank you for the clarification. The way I understood the Trinity was they have no form, and because Christ has a form, that is where my question came from

Comment: @TheFreemason I don't have a big understanding of the Trinity which is why I was asking the question, not trying to poke holes in the Trinity, but to understand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Trinitarians believe that Jesus being human does not contradict his status as God (or as the Spirit).

Even though Jesus is God, he **made** himself into physical human being, and through this he was able to experience life fully as a man.

> **Philippians 2:5-8 KJV** Let this mind be in you, which was also in Christ Jesus: Who, being in the form of God, thought it not robbery to be equal with God: But **made himself** of no reputation, and took upon him the form of a servant, and was made in the likeness of men: And being found in fashion as a man, he humbled himself, and became obedient unto death, even the death of the cross.
>
> **John 1:14-15 ESV** And the Word **became** flesh and dwelt among us, and we have seen his glory, glory as of the only Son from the Father, full of grace and truth. (John bore witness about him, and cried out, “This was he of whom I said, ‘He who comes after me ranks before me, because he was before me.’”)

Yet at the same time, Jesus was fully God.

> **Hebrews 2:9-10 ESV** But we see him who for a little while was made lower than the angels, namely Jesus, crowned with glory and honor because of the suffering of death, so that by the grace of God he might taste death for everyone. For it was fitting that he, **for whom and by whom all things exist**, in bringing many sons to glory, should make the founder of their salvation perfect through suffering.

Comment: It might also be helpful to speak of his existence prior to His incarnation, per John 1:1.

Comment: @AffableGeek Ya you're right.

Answer (score 1):

A basis for understanding can be found in the [Council of Chalcedon](http://www.ccel.org/ccel/schaff/creeds2.iv.i.iii.html):

> "We, then, following the holy Fathers, all with one consent, teach men to confess one and the same Son, our Lord Jesus Christ, the same perfect in Godhead and also perfect in manhood; truly God and truly man, of a reasonable [rational] soul and body; consubstantial [coessential] with the Father according to the Godhead, and consubstantial with us according to the Manhood; in all things like unto us, without sin; begotten before all ages of the Father according to the Godhead, and in these latter days, for us and for our salvation, born of the Virgin Mary, the Mother of God, according to the Manhood; one and the same Christ, Son, Lord, Only-begotten, to be acknowledged in two natures, inconfusedly, unchangeably, indivisibly, inseparably; the distinction of natures being by no means taken away by the union, but rather the property of each nature being preserved, and concurring in one Person and one Subsistence, not parted or divided into two persons, but one and the same Son, and only begotten, God the Word, the Lord Jesus Christ, as the prophets from the beginning [have declared] concerning him, and the Lord Jesus Christ himself has taught us, and the Creed of the holy Fathers has handed down to us".

So there is no problem with the union of Humanity and Divinity in Jesus, neither before nor after resurrection, if you accept Chalcedon. The main branches of Christianity do; therefore, their faithful can't imagine Jesus in Heaven, sitting on the right hand of the Father, in the communion of the Holy Ghost, without His resurrected body.